# Horizontal dataset from Vertical List

Tags: excel, excel-2007

please help me to sort out this issue. here shows my excel file.

```
exist view  

  A
---------   
john    
---------
kandy   
---------
mary    
---------
hatton  
---------
anne    
---------
galle   
---------


need to be like this    

  A
------------------
john    kandy
------------------
mary    hatton
------------------
anne    galle
------------------
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you'd like to be name and surname in one column (with space beetwen them), you can use next formula, say, in `B1` and drag it down:

`=INDEX($A$1:$A$7,(ROW($A1)-ROW($A$1))*2+1) & " " & INDEX($A$1:$A$7,(ROW($A1)-ROW($A$1))*2+2)`

[image]

---

Or, if you'd like to be name and surname in different columns, use next formulas.

- for `B1` : `=INDEX($A$1:$A$7,(ROW($A1)-ROW($A$1))*2+1)`
- for `C1` : `=INDEX($A$1:$A$7,(ROW($A1)-ROW($A$1))*2+2)`

and drag them down:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Using indirect

```
=INDIRECT("A" & 2*ROWS($A$1:A1)-1) & " " & INDIRECT("A" & 2*ROWS($A$1:A1))
```

And using offset :)

```
=OFFSET($A$1;2*(ROWS($A$1:$A1)-1);0) & " " & OFFSET($A$2;2*(ROWS($A$1:$A1)-1);0)
```